# pass a long string in Ajax actionlink

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-2

I need to pass a long string to my action method using ajax action link,but I'm getting a error says "Query string is very long"
If I use the normal action link then this issue is not there.

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Back", "Navigate", "mycontroller",new {value=mystring}, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "resultView", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, LoadingElementId = "pageloaddiv" }, new {  type = "submit"})
```

Is there any way, that I can achieve this using the ajax.Actionlink ?

Answer (score 1):

GET method has a limit for data

> Although the specification of the HTTP protocol does not specify any
>   maximum length, practical limits are imposed by web browser and server
>   software. http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

use POST method in jquery, use $.post(paras) instead $.get(paras).